# How to change default logo for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to add a custom logo to my Jenkins page which should appear on login page and post login pages as well.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried using Simple Theme Plugin to replace logo post login.

Answer (score 4):

1. As others pointed out, install the Login Page Theme plugin
2. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Login Page Theme
3. To change the logo, simply add the following style element in the Head section

```html
<style>
    .simple-page .logo {
        background-image: url('https://www.jenkins.io/images/logos/snow/snow.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 0;
        height: 350px;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    .simple-page form {
        width: unset;
        max-width: unset;
    }
<style>
```

4. To change the header text shown below the logo, add the following script element in the Header section

```html
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent = 'Welcome to Balajee\'s Jenkins!'
</script>
```

5. Finally hit save and apply.

When you login next time, you should see something like this

[image: Customized Jenkins Login Page]

As [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/login-theme/) clearly says..

> Only install this plugin, or make it available for installation, if you trust all your Jenkins administrators not to abuse these options.

Comment: If I use the proposed snippets, my login page is just all white. Any hints?

Comment: @sschuberth, not sure, maybe check the console logs and see if something is off. I doubt that the plugin might be broken with the newer version of Jenkins

Comment: If you read other comments, @sero posted that its not working with version 2.354

Comment: Not closing the `<style>` tag might be the issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read this post on the Jenkins blog (assuming Jenkins >= 2.128):

[New design, UX and extensibility digest for login page et. al.](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/06/27/new-login-page)

### Overview

... New design for the login and signup forms and Jenkins is (re)starting pages introduced in Jenkins 2.128 ... This meant to drop the usage of the jelly layout lib `(aka xmlns:l="/lib/layout")` and as well the page decorators it supported. However there is a new `SimplePageDecorator` extension point.

### SimplePageDecorator - custom implementations

Have a look at [Login Theme Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/login-theme), which allows you to configure your own custom content to be injected into the new login/sign-up page.

---

The [Simple Theme plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-theme-plugin) can be used to customize the rest of the pages.

Comment: Is there any example that you can point out for making this customization? I tried to used the sample given over here -https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/06/27/new-login-page/ but I see no styles applied with the errors in console.

Comment: Post a question with the errors from the logs. So much has changed in 2 years w/Jenkins, security and UI. Add a link to this one is the Q.

Comment: I have just figured out a way, the plugin expects a plain html content to be shoved into the existing page elements. So I tried to use a plain Style tag to change the logo and script tag to make changes to the header.

Comment: Added my answer to this this question

Comment: I am using 2.354 Jenkins.

When i load Login Theme plugin I get only blank screen at logon.

Then i have to manually remove login theme plugin to be able to login again :(

Brgds, S.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins changed the layout of the login page recently, and it's now much easier to change both the login logo, and the logo on the top left of all pages.  You'll need the both the [Login Theme Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/login-theme/) and [Simple Theme Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-theme-plugin/)

Once these are installed, go to Manage Jenkins -> Appearance.

In the Customizable theme/Extra CSS box enter...

```css
#jenkins-head-icon {
    content:url("https://example.com/path/to/new/logo.svg");
}
```

In the Login Page Theme/Footer, enter...

```html
<style>
    img[alt="logo"] {
        content:url("https://example.com/path/to/new/logo.svg");
    }
<style>
```